# How to throw a messages in django form that it is not changed the data in the form in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that been populated data in Updateview i want to check or throw a message that the form hasn't had changes when clicking the submit button

I'm glad that you can help me in this matter I can't understand some logic about this.

Comment: you should show us the code you're writing to try to do this. As it stands now, your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Sorry if i don't post the code i just want a broad understanding how you can make this kind of logic in code

Comment: I been trying the `form.has_changed` method in CBV updateview when the time that i hit the update button the message **Update Succesfully will show** without changing the data in the form i all want is to show another messages like **No Changes occur in the redirecting pages** so far i just come up in this thing

Comment: you have to post your code if you want help. we can't guess what you're doing. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `ModelForm` you can access `self.instance` during an update.

This allows you to compare you instance's fields with the cleaned_data to see if any is different.

Then you can raise a [ValidationError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror) if no field has been modified.

Comment: Instead of comparing to `self.instance` it's easier to check `self.has_changed()`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed)

Comment: I try the `form.has_changed()` but when i try to submit it will pop up my update messages that the form updated I want the logic when i update it without changing the form data instead the success message will pop out when redirecting the **No Changes Occur** will show